# Gmail API read metadata only scope

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using a service account and domain wide delegation to access all email accounts under client's domain with read-only scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly  In the message [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) request I use format option "metadata" with fields='payload/headers' which returns only email headers but not the content of the message.

Is there a way to restrict my app access to metadata only and not the content of the emails? This would ensure that my application can not read sensitive email content information and have access to metadata only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata`.
See https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata
Read resources metadata including labels, history records, and email message headers, but not the message body or attachments

Comment: You are right. Looks like @Eric team see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30945159/2827877 has implemented this feature as of November 2016 https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/release-notes

Comment: Yep, we did add a metadata scope, updated my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

The Gmail API now (as of November 2016) does support a gmail.metadata scope!
C.f.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

It allows access to email headers, including subject, without email message data.  Calls to message.get() with format=METADATA and format=MINIMAL will work with that scope, but not, for example, format=FULL or format=RAW.

Comment: API already defines metadata format in the docs as "Returns only email message ID, labels, and email headers". "Subject" is part of the headers. Could messages.list by "q" search metadata and not the body?

Comment: It doesn't allow free form ("q" search) today, as that searches more than just metadata by default.  You can do label-based searches still using the "labelIds" field.

Comment: @EricD given the recent improvements to protect user privacy in Gmail (e.g. domain owners whitelisting apps), we're trying to restrict our app to use the gmail.metadata scope. Unfortunately, we need to execute messages.list calls with the 'q' parameter, but _only_ to access message IDs in a range of time (using after:). I've filed a feature request to allow the use of the 'q' param on messages.list calls with the metadata scope, when the 'q' param is tied to metadata alone: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62062921 . Is that something y'all would consider implementing?

Comment: @EricD along the same lines, we'd love to have a scope isolated to adding / removing labels, requested here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759583. Is that something on the team's radar, too? Is there a better way to work with the Gmail API team than via the issue tracker? I've raised and commented on a couple of issues there but haven't heard anything back

Answer (score 0):

You can get only the specified headers via specifying 'format'=>'metadata' and 'metadataHeaders'=>array(headers you want to receive, excluding others). Check a sample get request in PHP below:

```
$service->users_messages->get($userId, $message->id,array('format'=>'metadata', 'metadataHeaders'=>array('From','To')));
```

The above code will only get From and To headers and wont show Subject header.

Hope this helps.