# When using gmail.metadata, how to limit by date range

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

I used to fetch data by accessing the full email and using the payload/headers options, but then spotted gmail.metadata. However I have just noticed this stops us being able to use the "q" parameter to let us filter by date. My plan was the first sync did from `T=0` and subsequent syncs used a "high watermark". My previously working watermark code now returns  `Metadata scope does not support 'q' parameter status_code: 403`.

Does anyone know a way to use the GMail metadata API without having to fetch through **all** emails every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*If you use the metadata scope there's no way of filtering the results you get from the query alone.*

#### More Information:

As per the documentation on `users.messages: list` (emphasis my own):

> **`q`:** `string`
>
> > Only return messages matching the specified query. Supports the same query format as the Gmail search box. For example, "`from:someuser@example.com rfc822msgid:<somemsgid@example.com> is:unread`". **Parameter cannot be used when accessing the api using the gmail.metadata scope.**

And from the Choose Auth Scopes page:

> **`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata`**
>
> > Read resources metadata including labels, history records, and email message headers, but not the message body or attachments.

This is by design. The `q` parameter allows for searching messages within fields which are restricted by the metadata scope - including message body and attachments. As a result, it is not possible whatsoever to filter results when using the metadata scope.

#### Feature Request:

On the flip side however, Google already knows about this, and a Feature Request for this has been made on their Issue Tracker. You can view this feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62062921), to which you can click the star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people want this feature to be implemented.

#### References:

- [Method: users.messages.list | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
- [Choose Auth Scopes | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)

#### Related Questions/Answers:

- [Gmail API read metadata only scope - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30945159)
  <sub>*check out answer and comments by [Eric D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3758997/eric-d), Gmail Engineer*</sub>

Comment: Thanks Rafa - I'd read the docs stating it wasn't available... I was hoping a wizard had found a workaround. 

I shall star the feature request!